# Where to install and reference ios in-app purchase content with phonegap

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova, jquery-mobile, in-app-purchase

Have a phonegap app that supports in-app purchases. I'm able to purchase and download the content just fine. I'm placing the content in my apps' documents folder 
(e.g. /var/mobile/Applications/2148FA13-BCB1-1825-AACF-324D008D1626/Documents/assets)

The content consists of several images and a css file that references them. I need to refer to the Documents/assets/main.css file from my html page in phonegap. I've tried

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/var/mobile/Applications/2148FA13-BCB1-1825-AACF-324D008D1626/Documents/assets/main.css" type="text/css" />
```

without any luck.

Any ideas on how I can reference this file in ios or is there a more appropriate directory to use here (my apps www dir)?

Comment: link works fine... the references inside it were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access them directly instead you should use :

```
getAbsolutePath("mead.jpg",
                        function(entry){
                            //alert(entry.fullPath);
                            $("#img_test").attr("src",entry.fullPath);
                            console.log("jq$:=" + entry.fullPath);
                            //$("#img_test").attr("src","img/test.jpg");
                        });

// file system
    function getAbsolutePath(file_name,call_back){
        var full_path = "";
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
               function (file_system){
                    file_system.root.getFile(
                        file_name, 
                        {create: false},
                        call_back
                        , 
                        function(){
                            console.log("failed to fetch file, please check the name");
                        }
                    );

                }, 
                function(){
                    console.log("failed file sytem");
                }
        );


    }
```